# How can I write web browser Javascript console output and stack traces to stdout & stderr?

Tags: javascript, browser, stdout, stderr, trace

I am currently using Chromium for my Javascript web development, but I would be happy to get output to standard output from any web browser.

My development environment, which is Emacs, is optimised for development environments which write "print" statements to stdout and stack traces to stderr. Both stdout & stderr are easily captured into the Emacs buffer running the process which is running the application under development.

I can run a browser process from Emacs, and I see standard output & error messages in my Emacs buffer, but I don't see any console output or stacktraces from my Javascript code.

Short of hacking the source code for the browser itself, is there any easy way to make this happen? Maybe a browser extension?

Comment: You did not consider running a headless browser?

Comment: have you found a way?